# Acer Aspire 7741Z cannot install Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, bsod, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 7741Z that crashed on me and I had to replace the HDD.  I didn't have a Windows disk to use for install so I installed Ubuntu.  It works, it boots, everything is fine.  Now I have a Windows XP CD with key (I got a full version of XP because I have an upgrade-only version of Windows 7, but that's the next step).  I boot from CD for XP Home install and it gets through some of the basic "do this to install RAID driver" and all of that good stuff, so *something* is happening in there.  Then I get the BSOD error like the screenshot below.

[image: http://i332.photobucket.com/albums/m330/jtl310/bsod-compressed.jpg]

So my question is how does Linux install just fine and Windows pukes all over itself?  I considered a BIOS upgrade, but the Acer download site only has executables from inside Windows.  I'm comfortable with flashing the BIOS if needed, but I'm not even sure if that's the next step.

Any suggestions?

PS - I'm actually writing this from Ubuntu on the problem machine :)

Comment: check out this link. http://tinyurl.com/nq5z3op hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

I did it a few years back. I had had the same issue on my Acer. We created a bootable USB thumbdrive for the installation. Here are the steps for doing that: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-USB-Bootable and then I was able to book to the USB, and format the HD from the USB drive. Then I was able to do the install just fine. But I didn't want to keep linux on that machine, so if you want to keep both, then there are other steps you need to take instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SATA mode in your bios from AHCI to default or compatible. It's normally the only other option. This makes the drive compatible with Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install windows onto a harddisk you need to be able to access that harddisk. In the past (e.g. win98 era) this requires finding or selecting the right drivers, or praying that the basic install CD of install floppy already came with the right driver on them.

This was a hassle.

Moving forward to the Windows XP era:
The number of different chipsets <sup>*1</sup>in consumer devices has decreased. At the same time the default install CD/DVD ships with many drivers and on the first boot it tries to figure out which one to use and installs that automatically.

This works for most hardware. If you have an exotic setup<sup>*2</sup> then you can install the drivers during the installation by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and inserting the floppy with the right driver.

Moving forward to the end of the Windows XP era:
Hardware from this time period usually shipped with Serial ATA (SATA) rather then the old paralel ATA. This new ATA version is incompatible and you need AHCI drivers.

To easy the transition many motherboards shipped with SATA, but allowed you to configure them for ancient legacy mode, or as modern AHCI.

This is why JohnnyVegas's answer suggest to configure SATA in the BIOS to legacy mode.

Either doing that, or loading *the right driver* **from floppy**<sup>*2</sup> will work for XP.

> it gets through some of the basic "do this to install RAID driver" 
>   and all of that good stuff, so something is happening in there. 
>   Then I get the BSOD error like the screenshot below...

Here we need to pause:

Which 'RAID' drivers did you install?
How is the BIOS configured?

1. Backward compatible legacy ATA mode? (Should work out of the box).
2. AHCI mode (More feature, often faster. Supported out of the box by win7).
3. Some kind of RAID mode?

Depending on the answer to those you need to find the right kind of drivers.

All of this assuming that you have the same problem which most people have with these kind of upgrades.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: These chipsets typically include the controller which speaks to the disks.

<sup>*2</sup>Exotic as in "not the usual consumer stuff. E.g. SCSI cards, or **RAID** controllers).

<sup>*3</sup>From floppy as in:

- From an actual hardware floppy on a truly old floppy controller.
- Or from a limited set of USB diskdrivers (I think four specific models were supported when XP came out.
- Or by slipstreaming the right driver onto the XP installation medium.